# Why can't I view Laravel photos?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to view photos saved in the directory / storage / images / photoByVolontariusz / but unfortunately without successfully. Of course I do it in Laravel. What am I doing wrong?
This is how I try to display it:

```
 @foreach ($dodaneZdjecia as $dodaneZdjecia)

<img src="{{ URL::asset($dodaneZdjecia->path) }}" width="100px" height="70px" class="img-thumbnail">

@endforeach
```

The path to the file saved in the database, of course, matches what should be displayed on the page

Comment: What is the result of html output of this code? I mean what is the value of `$dodaneZdjecia->path` ? And what is your files' physical path?

Comment: The directory /storage/images/ is not public. You can use the directory storage/app/public/images if you link the storage folder with `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Don't use same name for collection and iteration in loop.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's `storage` directory is not accessible by HTTP. So; if your files is directly under `storage/images/photoByVolontariusz` browser can't access them by requesting `http://yoursite.com/storage/images/photoByVolontariusz/foo.jpg`

If you want your uploaded files to be publicly available with HTTP requests, you need to put them in your applications public storage directory: `storage/app/public` and have a symlink to it from your `public` directory.

Laravel documentation's Structure page's [The Storage Directory](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure#the-storage-directory) section described this:

> The `storage/app/public` directory may be used to store user-generated
> files, such as profile avatars, that should be publicly accessible.
> You should create a symbolic link at `public/storage` which points to
> this directory. You may create the link using the `php artisan storage:link` Artisan command.

So, when you uploading your files you need to use [The Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk).

Answer (score 0):

post your database and controller image here.
code given above is correct way to view photo

```
<img src="{{asset('images/'.$data->image)}}" width="48" height="48" alt="User" />
```

but for this to run you need to store your image inside a folder in public then fatch it